# Display title over image in ionic2Slides

Tags: ionic2

How to add text over the image in ionic1 slides

i need to display the text over image in the ionic slide. what should be stylesheet value for the text i need to set?
here is title property.

```
.slide-title {
    margin-top: 2.8rem;

  }
```

and here is the image property

```
.slide-image {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 18px 0;
  }
```

and here is the code for displaying slides

```
<ion-slides pager>
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides">
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons end>
          <button ion-button color="primary">Skip</button>
        </ion-buttons>
      </ion-toolbar>
      <img [src]="slide.image" class="slide-image" width="100%" height="100%"/>
      <h2 class="slide-title" [innerHTML]="slide.title"></h2>
      <p [innerHTML]="slide.description"></p>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      <ion-toolbar>
      </ion-toolbar>
      <img src="assets/img/ica-slidebox-img-4.png" class="slide-image"/>
      <h2 class="slide-title">Ready to Play?</h2>
      <button ion-button large clear icon-right color="primary">
        Continue
        <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 ways to do this:

1. Setting the image as `background-url` to the outermost container. And then specify the title and other things in this container.
2. Outermost container will have `position: relative`. Have your image `<img/>` inside this container. All other inner containers (title and etc), will have `position: absolute;` and then actual position accordingly. Like `top: 5%; left: 5%;`

I have tried both the solutions in my app in the past. Both works. Not tried with your code though. Let me know about specifics if you need.